# Connecting QSslSocket with OpenSSL server

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to connect SSL sockets between my Qt application (using QSslSockets) and my c++ server running SSL sockets (using openssl)..

Server Code:

```
int create_socket(int port)
{
   int s;
   struct sockaddr_in addr;

   addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   addr.sin_port = htons(port);
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

   s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (s < 0) {
      perror("Unable to create socket");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
      perror("Unable to bind");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if (listen(s, 1) < 0) {
      perror("Unable to listen");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   return s;
}

void init_openssl()
{
   SSL_load_error_strings();
   OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
}

void cleanup_openssl()
{
   EVP_cleanup();
}

 SSL_CTX *create_context()
{
   const SSL_METHOD *method;
   SSL_CTX *ctx;
   method = SSLv23_server_method();
   ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
   if (!ctx) {
      perror("Unable to create SSL context");
      ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   return ctx;
}

void configure_context(SSL_CTX *ctx)
{    
   if(SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "/root/myCA/server_crt.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) > 0)
   {
      std::cout<<"Cert found"<<std::endl;
   }
   if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "/root/myCA/server_key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) > 0 ) {
      std::cout<<"Key found"<<std::endl;
   }
   if(SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) > 0)
   {
      std::cout<<"Key valid"<<std::endl;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int sock;
   SSL_CTX *ctx;

   init_openssl();
   ctx = create_context();

   configure_context(ctx);
   sock = create_socket(3000);

   while(1) {
       struct sockaddr_in addr;
       uint len = sizeof(addr);
       SSL *ssl;
       const char reply[] = "test\n";

      int client = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
      if (client > 0) {
          std::cout<<"Client accepted..."<<std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
          perror("Unable to accept");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
      SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);

      if (SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0) {
          ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
      }
      else {
          SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply));
      }

      SSL_free(ssl);
      close(client);
    }
  close(sock);
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
  cleanup_openssl();
```

}

Qt Client Code:

```
 SSLSOCKET::SSLSOCKET(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
 {
   connect(&client,SIGNAL(encrypted()),this,SLOT(ConnectionEstablished()));
   connect(&client,SIGNAL(sslErrors(const QList<QSslError>&)),this,SLOT(ErrorOccured(const QList<QSslError> &)));
   QList<QSslCertificate>
   trusted_ca=QSslCertificate::fromPath("/Users/test/Desktop/server_crt.pem");
   if(trusted_ca.empty())
   {
      qDebug()<<"Error not trusted Ca.";
   }
   client.setCaCertificates(trusted_ca);
   client.connectToHostEncrypted(*my ip address*,3000);
 }

 void SSLSOCKET::ErrorOccured(const QList<QSslError> &error)
 {
    qDebug()<<"ERROR HERE----:";
    qDebug()<<error;
 }

 void SSLSOCKET::ConnectionEstablished()
 {
    qDebug()<<"CONNECTION WORKED------:";
    if(!client.waitForEncrypted())
    {
       qDebug()<<client.errorString();
    }
    else
    {
       qDebug()<<"Encrypted Connection Established...";
    }
  }
```

I can see the connection being made between the client and server, however the client.waitForEncrypted() is showing 'Unknown Error'..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `waitForEncrypted()` inside of your `connected()` handler.  The client hasn't actually initiated the SSL handshake yet, so you can't wait on it yet.  Per the [`connectToHostEncrypted()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html#connectToHostEncrypted) documentation:

> Starts an encrypted connection to the device `hostname` on `port`, using `mode` as the `OpenMode`. This is equivalent to calling `connectToHost()` to establish the connection, followed by a call to `startClientEncryption()`. The `protocol` parameter can be used to specify which network protocol to use (eg. IPv4 or IPv6).
>
> `QSslSocket` first enters the `HostLookupState`. Then, after entering either the event loop or one of the `waitFor...()` functions, it enters the `ConnectingState`, **emits `connected()`, and then initiates the SSL client handshake**. At each state change, `QSslSocket` emits signal `stateChanged()`.

If you want to handle `connected()` like this, you will have to use [`connectToHost()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#connectToHost) instead of `connectToHostEncrypted()`, and then call [`startClientEncryption()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html#startClientEncryption) separately:

```
SSLSOCKET::SSLSOCKET(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
{
    connect(&client, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(ConnectionEstablished()));
    ...
    client.connectToHost(*my ip address*, 3000);
}

void SSLSOCKET::ConnectionEstablished()
{
    client.startClientEncryption();
    if (!client.waitForEncrypted())
        ...
}
```

---

**EDIT**: scratch that.  I thought you were handling the `connected()` signal, but I see now that you are handling the `encrypted()` signal instead.  In that case:

> If the SSL handshake is successful, `QSslSocket` emits `encrypted()`.

So you don't need to use `waitForEncrypted()` at all:

```
void SSLSOCKET::ConnectionEstablished()
{
    qDebug()<<"CONNECTION WORKED------:";
    qDebug()<<"Encrypted Connection Established...";
}
```

Even if you did call it, it should simply return true:

> Waits until the socket has completed the SSL handshake and has emitted `encrypted()`, or `msecs` milliseconds, whichever comes first. **If `encrypted()` has been emitted, this function returns true**; otherwise (e.g., the socket is disconnected, or the SSL handshake fails), false is returned.

So, unless the socket is being disconnected after the handshake completes, or `encrypted()` is being emitted before the encrypted state is actually changed, or some other unforeseen error is occurring, I don't see any reason for `waitForEncrypted()` to return false inside of the `encrypted()` handler.

Comment: Thanks - what is the best way to see the status of the SSL handshake from Qt? I.e. it looks like something is failing and not sustaining the connection, therefore need to work out where this is....